# Term for describing the signs/marks placed over a symbol/letter

Tags: notation, terminology

This is probably a rather simple question but i couldn't find a proper way to google this since I'm just lacking the correct term.

So, we have subscripts $x_1$ and superscripts $x^1$ but how do we call signs that are placed directly on top of the symbols denoting a variable e.g. $\hat{x}$, $\bar{x}$, $\dot{x}$ etc.

My main purpose for this is to form a sentence like: "The [insert word here] of the symbol is denoting [concept]" where I associate a different meaning for each sign/mark above each symbol/letter to represent a certain class within that concept.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a name for that type of notation specifically, but colleagues of mine have used the term "decoration" for general accent-like marks applied to a symbol. (The specific context was different cohomology theories distinguished in notation only by tildes, haceks, etc.)

Comment: @anomaly I see, thanks for that input. However, I feel like before I use "decorations" I'm better off saying "symbols over variables" or something along those lines since it's probably easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so they are called **DIACRITICS** in general. This isn't a specifically mathematical term, more of a typographical feature in general. But that's the closest I got to.

***As for ^***, I was used to calling it a "cap"/"hat". Went online to search for "cap-notation". Found an article on the "exponential" symbol. It was named **Caret**. So it's called that.

The other two. I call one of them a "**bar**", i.e. "x-barred" as per your case. Turns out, it's called an **Overscore**. (I guess I'm waiting for the side-score to finally appear someday...?) Also popular as "Vinculum"... rings bells, eh?

The last one is called a **"Tittle"**. It may also be called a *superscript dot*, this implying that it's not necessary to have superscripts on the upper **corner** of a letter.

That's it. Thanks.

Oh the sources!

[**Tittle** aka overhead dot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle?wprov=sfla1)

[**Overscore** aka bar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline?wprov=sfla1)

[**Caret** or the hat or cap or exponential symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret?wprov=sfla1)

[**Diacritics or Accent marks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic?wprov=sfla1) which mostly appear overhead, but can do so below as well.

Comment: This does only apply for $\hat{x}$ (hat or caret). I want to describe all possibilities of such a symbol such as hat, bar, dot, etc.

Comment: Right, sorry I misinterpreted in haste. Posting something soon...

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I looked it up and **diacritic** are a general class of accents to a letter. These are not limited to above the symbol but can also be placed below the symbol. So, the correct term would probably be **superscript diacritics**